# Nvidia force underclocking in a dual monitor setup

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, underclock

Not a gamer, no need for 3D or any bells & whistles other than running a dual monitor setup *without* having GPU pinned to heat generating maximum performance.

New Dell Precision M4700
Nvidia Quadro K1000M
Driver version: 304.60

With my old laptop I was able to PowerMizer throttle the GPU in a dual monitor setup (GeForce GT 330M)

```
Option "Coolbits" "1"
Option "RegistryDwords" "PowerMizerEnable=0x1; PowerMizerLevel=0x3; PowerMizerDefault=0x3; PowerMizerDefaultAC=0x3"
```

The above force throttled GPU freq from 900MHz to 135MHz on battery and AC, which drastically reduced GPU temperature, keeping laptop fans quiet as a result.

Now Nvidia appears to have taken Coolbits out of the picture entirely, forcing max performance in multi monitor configurations, and taking the ability to underclock completely out of the end user's hands, horrible, horrible, horrible.

Has anyone found a way to circumvent this POS driver and force downclock the GPU? Am wondering if reverting to a 173 series driver might do the trick, if it will somehow recognize newer cards.

Such a shame, CPU governors work fantastically well on the M4700, CPU idle temps consistently in the low 40s while the GPU idles in the low 50s, ridiculous, would have a whisper quiet machine otherwise.

Comment: I've the same problem (also dell m4700, k1000m). did you found a solution?

Comment: yes, I did, flash the vBIOS, only solution for Linux, AFAIK

Comment: nice! I found your post here: http://forum.notebookreview.com/dell-latitude-vostro-precision/682758-m4700-owners-thread-72-print.html
however, i have still fan spinups with :( maybe you can share your exact settings in "Kepler BIOS Tweaker" (screenshots please)?